# How can I remove bottom of image

Tags: css, sass

how can I remove or cut the bottom piece of an image so that it's hidden instead of sticking out of the div?
(I have an image of a phone and instead of the bottom piece sticking out of the div I want it to be hidden) any suggestions?
(p.s. I've tried max-height and overflow hidden)

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] showing us the issue

Comment: it wont show on the snippet since its the relative path I'm using and I can't get an image address so you won't see the image.

Comment: There are plenty of free placeholder image sites you can use to simulate the image you have. E.g. https://placeholder.com/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.no-overflow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black; 
  
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="no-overflow">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200">
</div>

<div class="overflow">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200">
</div>
```

Do this if there's no content other than the image. If there is, you'll have to crop the image yourself to replicate the effect

Answer (score 0):

I put overflow hidden on the image that's why it didn't work, it worked when I set overflow:hidden to the div.